# Use Azure Key Vault Secrets for Unit Tests in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, nunit, .net-5, azure-keyvault, azure-secrets

I have a solution in .NET 5 with some Unit Tests in NUnit that required some secrets to work correctly. Testing in Visual Studio using local user secrets works fine but now I want to try to integrate using Azure Key Vault and run the Unit Tests inside a Pipeline.

I added the Task `AzureKeyVault@2` and according to the log the secrets are *downloaded* just fine but in the next steps, the Unit Tests fail because it doesn't find some keys when try to access from `IConfiguration`.

This is my `azure-pipelines.yml` (only the relevant parts).

```yaml
- job: Init
  displayName: Unit Testing
  variables:
    solutionToBuild: 'Solution.sln'
    unitTestsProject: 'UnitTests\UnitTests.csproj'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Packages'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '$(solutionToBuild)'
      verbosityRestore: minimal
      feedsToUse: 'select'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Solution'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '$(solutionToBuild)'
      arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration)'

  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    displayName: 'Configure Key Vault'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '**-etc-**'
      KeyVaultName: '**key-vault-name**'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '$(unitTestsProject)'
      arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'
      publishTestResults: true
```

I created this basic tests that are currently failing in the Pipeline. I'm using the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` method to initialize all the unit tests.

```cs
[Test]
[TestCase("secret-key-1")]
[TestCase("secret-key-1")]
public void TestSecrets(string key)
{
    Assert.NotNull(_config[key]);
    Assert.IsNotEmpty(_config[key]);
}
```

Does the `AzureKeyVault@2` pass the secrets keys and values for the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task or do I need an additional step?. I read that you can play with the [FileTransform@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) step using an empty `appsettings.json` but I couldn't make it work. Is there a correct method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work. I decided to go to the route of the `appsettings.json`. with File Transformation Task. I will answer myself just in case anyone else find this useful.

You need to have a `appsettings.json` in your Unit Test project, and add all the required keys you'll need in your Unit Tests, but without values, only `""`, e.g.

```json
{
  "secret-key-1": "",
  "secret-key-2": "",
  "secret-key-3": "",
}
```

If you want to test locally you can use the local user-secrets option in Visual Studio and add all the keys like in your `appsettings.json` file but with actual values (you'll be the only one to view the values anyways)

[image: Manage user secrets]

```json
{
  "secret-key-1": "some-secret-value",
  "secret-key-2": "some-secret-value",
  "secret-key-3": "some-secret-value",
}
```

Then, in your `SetUp` method you can initialize the `IConfiguration` class as follow. (You can easily transform this into a static method if you have multiple Unit Tests classes)

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class MyUnitTest

   private IConfiguration Config;

   [SetUp]
   public void Setup()
   {
       Config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .Build();
   }

   [Test]
   [TestCase("secret-key-1")
   [TestCase("secret-key-2")
   public void TestKeys(string key)
   {
      Assert.NotNull(config[key]);
      Assert.IsNotEmpty(config[key]);
   }
}
```

Finally, in the `azure-pipelines.yml` you add the `FileTransform@1` Task after the `AzureKeyVault@2`.

```yml
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    displayName: 'Configure Key Vault'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '**-etc-**'
      KeyVaultName: '**key-vault-name**'

  - task: FileTransform@1
    displayName: 'Set Unit Tests Settings'
    inputs:
      folderPath: '$(projectsDirectory)'
      fileType: 'json'
      targetFiles: '**/appsettings.json'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '$(unitTestsProject)'
      arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'
      publishTestResults: true
```

And that's it, after that in the pipeline log you'll see something like this in the `FileTransform@1` task

```txt
Applying JSON variable substitution for **/appsettings.json
Applying JSON variable substitution for D:\a\1\s\UnitTests\appsettings.json
Substituting value on key secret-key-1 with (string) value: ***
Substituting value on key secret-key-2 with (string) value: ***
Substituting value on key secret-key-3 with (string) value: ***
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Keyvault task in the pipeline to fetch the  secrets in your keyvault :

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
    displayName: 'Configure Key Vault'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '**-etc-**'
      KeyVaultName: '**key-vault-name**'
      SecretsFilter: '*'
      RunAsPreJob: false
```

Now, in the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task, add environment variables to define the keyvault secrets so that you can use these environment variables inside your project :

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 
  displayName: ''
  env:
    MySecret: $(key-vault-secret-name)
  inputs:
    command: ''
    projects: 'project-name'
```

Inside your project, you can define the keyvault secret as follows :

```
var mySecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySecret");
```

Reference : [Azure DevOps YAML pipeline : Use Azure KeyVault secret as Environment Variable - DEV Community](https://dev.to/kenakamu/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-use-azure-keyvault-secret-as-environment-variable-45g6)

Comment: Hi @RamaraoAdapa-MT. I have a question. Do I need to add env for each Secret Key?. We have a lot of secrets (more than 20), and frequently adding more and I don't know if will be feasible to edit the yml file each time we update or add more secrets to the vault. It's the only way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use access the keyvault secrets directly from your .NET application. Please refer this : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1430794/Using-Csharp-NET-to-Read-and-Write-from-Azure-Key

Comment: I know, and in the app is working, but in the unit tests required a different approach. My other answer at the end solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved